# Is it possible to download entire YouTube playlist using IDM?

Tags: firefox, video, download, youtube, download-manager

I download youtube video using IDM. All I have to do is use Mozilla, install a some idm download plug in and there you go. You can see IDM "DOWNLOAD" label towards the top right corner, or you can simply just copy paste the video url into idm. But is there a way to geturl of all videos in a playlist? Just a way to download entire playlist with IDM with a single click?

Comment: I have not tried that method. This seems to be "it". But there is a problem. It seems like this method modifies theoriginal youtube video urls. I do not want that. Because my ISP has removed speed limit for youtube. I can download videos from youtube at top speed regardless of my internet plan. If the url gets modified. It is not recognized as youtube url. And therefore i will be downloading it at regular speed.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath post it as answer so I can mark it. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: If your a linux fan youtube-dl hosted on google can download complete playlists.

Comment: @TimWilliams No, I use windows. :)

Comment: Still [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) would work on Windows, you only need to install Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ByTubeD](http://msram.github.io/bytubed/dev-versions/1.1.2a2.xpi) plugin along with Mozilla firefox and [IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html). A video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-E_HXXwjsg) with detailed steps is available.

- Right click on youtube playlist, select ByTubeD. ByTubeD will grab
  all youtube video links in playlist.
- select appropriate video format and click start button.
- A list will be created in firefox new tab.
- Right click on any link and select option "Download all links with
  IDM" and click ok.

This plugin is awesome, but unfortunately it is not maintained at all. but available for download in github

Comment: Note that ByTubeD includes suggested videos to the generated list, too.